# add element containing ng-if using jquery after

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to add some validation to some input using a directive. I'm using the following code to add the validation alert but the ng-if doesn't seem to be registering and the messages are constantly displayed.

```
if (addMessages) {
    angular.element(element).after('<div><span ng-if="form.' + scope.fieldName + '.$error.maxlength">Please keep it under ' + property.length + ' characters.</span></div>' +
        '<div><span ng-if="form.' + scope.fieldName + '.$error.required">This field is required</span></div>')
    element.removeAttr("my-directive");
    $compile(element)(scope);
}
```

I originally tried to do this with ngMessages but they are not currently working on mdDialogs where most of my input is contained, so I came up with this solution, but its just not working for me.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code when you execute `$compile(element)(scope);` it is actually compiling the `element` which do not contain the html you just added in the previous line. It is because `element.after` adds the html after the `element`. So you have to get a reference to the dynamic element inserted and then call `$compile` on it, it should work fine.

```
if (addMessages) {
    var $htmlToInsert = $('<div><span ng-if="form.' + scope.fieldName + '.$error.maxlength">Please keep it under ' + property.length + ' characters.</span></div>' +
        '<div><span ng-if="form.' + scope.fieldName + '.$error.required">This field is required</span></div>');
    angular.element(element).after($htmlToInsert)
    element.removeAttr("my-directive");
    $compile($htmlToInsert)(scope);
}
```

**Demo** http://plnkr.co/edit/Vjt1PTGfbLa6zA0iRYSz?p=preview

Comment: Nope.  Still constantly displayed.